# Equation for the curve in terms of x,y

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, curves

we got the equation

$$r(t) = (t-2)i + (t^2+4)j$$

I got

$$x = 1-2t$$
$$y = 1+4t$$

Would that be correct?

Comment: Any more context?

Comment: @Quality that's all the problem said so I just did x = x0  + a*t and y = y0 + b*t

Comment: What is $i$ and $j$?

Comment: Why not: $x(t)=t-2$ and $y(t)=t^2+4$?

Comment: @zoli That seemed to simple, would that be correct?

Answer (score 1):

If Your equation is a vector equation:
$$
\vec r(t)= (t-2)\vec i +(t^2+4) \vec j
$$
where $\vec i$,$\vec j$ are the versors of the orthogonal basis, than you have:
$$
x=r_1=t-2 \qquad y=r_2=t^2+4
$$
So: $t=x+2$ and $y=(x+2)^2+4$.